# Matlab S-Function crashing when set to dynamically sized

Tags: matlab, simulink

i have following problem. I have created a S-Function which should read a matrix from a text file, where the output size of the output port is not known and therefore set as dynamically sized. Matlab is then crashing. When setting for fixed size, there is no problem. I hope someone could help me out

```
#define S_FUNCTION_NAME Data_Input
#define S_FUNCTION_LEVEL 2

/*---- Define size of input ports ---------------------------------------------------*/
#define OUTPUTSIZE     50                         
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include "simstruc.h"

int_T in;
/*---- Define data types ------------------------------------------------------------*/
typedef struct SBufferData
{
    real32_T   data[50];
    int32_T    number;
} SBuffer;

/*==== mdlCheckParameters ===========================================================*/
#undef MDL_CHECK_PARAMETERS                   /* Change to #undef to remove function */
#if defined(MDL_CHECK_PARAMETERS) && defined(MATLAB_MEX_FILE)

static void mdlCheckParameters(SimStruct *S)
{ 
}
#endif /* MDL_CHECK_PARAMETERS */
/*===================================================================================*/

/*=== mdlInitializeSizes ============================================================*/
static void mdlInitializeSizes(SimStruct *S)
{  
    ssSetNumSFcnParams(S,1);                   /* number of expected parameters      */

    ssSetSFcnParamTunable(S, 0, 0);            /* sets parameter 1 to be non-tunable */
    ssSetSFcnParamTunable(S, 1, 0);            /* sets parameter 2 to be non-tunable */

    ssSetNumContStates(S,0);                   /* number of continuous states        */
    ssSetNumDiscStates(S,0);                   /* number of discrete states          */

    ssSetNumInputPorts(S,0);                    /* number of input ports              */
    ssSetNumOutputPorts(S,1);                   /* number of output ports             */

    ssSetOutputPortWidth(S,0,DYNAMICALLY_SIZED);               /* first output port width            */
    ssSetOutputPortDataType(S,0,SS_SINGLE);    /* first output port data type        */


    ssSetNumSampleTimes(S,0);                  /* number of sample times             */

    ssSetNumRWork(S,0);                        /* number real work vector elements   */
    ssSetNumIWork(S,0);                        /* number int_T work vector elements  */
    ssSetNumPWork(S,1);                        /* number ptr work vector elements    */
    ssSetNumModes(S,0);                        /* number mode work vector elements   */
    ssSetNumNonsampledZCs(S,0);                /* number of nonsampled zero crossing */

    if (ssGetNumSFcnParams(S) != ssGetSFcnParamsCount(S)) {
        return; /* Parameter mismatch reported by the Simulink engine*/
    }
}
/*===================================================================================*/

/*==== mdlInitializeSampleTimes =====================================================*/
static void mdlInitializeSampleTimes(SimStruct *S)
{
    real_T dSampleTime=(mxGetPr(ssGetSFcnParam(S,0))[0]);

    ssSetSampleTime(S, 0, dSampleTime);
    ssSetOffsetTime(S, 0, 0.0);
}
/*===================================================================================*/

/*==== mdlStart =====================================================================*/
#define MDL_START                             /* Change to #undef to remove function */
#if defined(MDL_START)

static void mdlStart(SimStruct *S)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int_T i, index=0;

    SBuffer *buffer;
    float temp;
/*---- Retrieve pointer to pointers work vector -------------------------------------*/
    void **PWork = ssGetPWork(S);

    buffer = (SBuffer *)malloc(OUTPUTSIZE * sizeof(SBuffer));
    PWork[0] = (void *)buffer;

/*---- Read from text-file ----------------------------------------------------------*/
    fp = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");

    while(feof(fp)==0)
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%f",&temp);
        buffer -> data[index] = temp;
        index++;
    }

    buffer -> number = (int32_T) index;

    fclose(fp);
}
#endif /*  MDL_START */
/*===================================================================================*/

/*==== mdlOutputs ===================================================================*/
static void mdlOutputs(SimStruct *S, int_T tid)
{
/*---- Get input ports --------------------------------------------------------------*/
    real_T *y1=(real_T *)ssGetOutputPortSignal(S,0);

    int_T i;
    SBuffer *buffer;

/*---- Retrieve pointer to pointers work vector -------------------------------------*/
    void **PWork = ssGetPWork(S);

    buffer = PWork[0];

    for (i = 0; i < buffer->number; i++)
    {
        y1[i] = buffer->data[i];
    }

}
/*===================================================================================*/

/*==== mdlTerminate =================================================================*/
static void mdlTerminate(SimStruct *S) 
{
    SBuffer *buffer;

/*---- Retrieve pointer to pointers work vector -------------------------------------*/    
    void **PWork = ssGetPWork(S);

    buffer = PWork[0];

/*---- Deallocate structure 'info' and 'buffer' -------------------------------------*/
    free(buffer);
}
/*===================================================================================*/

/*==== Required S-function trailer ==================================================*/
#ifdef  MATLAB_MEX_FILE               /* Is this file being compiled as a MEX-file?  */
#include "simulink.c"                 /* MEX-file interface mechanism                */
#else
#include "cg_sfun.h"                  /* Code generation registration function       */
#endif
/*===================================================================================*/
```

Comment: You'll need to also supply an example text file that you are trying to read, and give some idea of what a simple model looks like.

Comment: Hi Phil, the text file is for example 

0  2  1  0  1  1  1  1 0 0 0

The s function should print out the values from the textfile as array (vector). The size of the array is not known and dynamic.

Comment: When you update the model, (not run it) what is the size shown on the signal lines from your block. You can view these by choosing menu option "Display"->"Signals and Ports"->"Signal Dimensions". If signal sizes are set to dynamic size it should max size with a ":" next to it. If this is not enough to hold your signal you will get a crash.